# strong-pm is fails to start. Throws "Unexpected end of input" answer

Tags: strongloop

I am using strong-pm on my ubuntu server for my node application. It was running all fine until it stopped one fine moment. Thereafter it doesnt start my service at all. tried restarting strong-pm and even rebooted my server. But in vain.
the strong-pm.log keeps throwing  the following log entry

```
Connection fails:  [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input]
It will be retried for the next request.
Listening failed with: Unexpected end of input
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at parseAndLoad (/usr/lib/node_modules/strong-pm/node_modules/strong-mesh-models/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/connectors/memory.js:122:21)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strong-pm/node_modules/strong-mesh-models/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/connectors/memory.js:108:9
    at fs.js:334:14
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strong-pm/node_modules/strong-docker-build/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:42:10
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strong-pm/node_modules/strong-docker-build/node_modules/fstream-npm/node_modules/fstream-ignore/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:42:10
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strong-pm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:42:10
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is syntax error in one off your model json  file or may be in datasource.json**

share your code for more help